# Is this a valid trig identity for sin(a)sin(b)?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm looking at a solution for a problem and one of the steps says that:

$\sin(100\pi t)\sin(500\pi t) = \frac{1}{2}[\sin(100\pi+500\pi)t-\sin(500\pi-100\pi)t]$

The thing is, I don't recognize that identity and can't find it searching online. Is it valid, or did the person who wrote the solution make a mistake?

As a side note, in the next step they somehow combine that to get:

$\frac{1}{2}\sin(200\pi)t$

Which I don't see how they did either.

Comment: do you have trig identities for $\sin(A+B)$ and $\sin(A-B)$? What happens if you use them on the right hand side of your equation?

Comment: @DavidSteinberg Substituting those identities into the right hand side results in $\cos(A)\sin(B)$, which is why I think the solution I'm looking at might be wrong. I also don't understand how they simplified it, as I mentioned at the end of my question..

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities

Comment: @Nate Sorry, I must have still been asleep. I don't think the equality is true. When you evaluate at t = 1/200, the right hand side is 0, and the left hand side is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the identity is the next:
$$\sin \theta \sin \varphi = {{\cos(\theta - \varphi) - \cos(\theta + \varphi)} \over 2}$$
Then applying it:
$$\sin(100\pi t)\sin(500\pi t) = \frac{[\cos(100\pi-500\pi)t-\cos(100\pi+500\pi)t]}{2}=\frac{[\cos(-400\pi)t-\cos(600\pi)t]}{2}$$
From that point I don't see how is possible to reduce it.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm pretty sure the solution I'm looking at is just wrong!